# PHP - Foreach loop get results

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I have this function below, that **should** list all the country codes from my database, that is present, and then count how many times each country code is present:

```
function getAvailableCountries(){
    global $dbh;

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT country_code,country_name FROM users WHERE country_code!='NA' AND country_name!='NA'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach ($rows as $row){
        $countryCode =  $row["country_code"];
        $countryName =  $row["country_name"];   
    }

    print "<option value='$countryCode'>$countryName</option>";

}
```

the `$countryCode` variable consists of: `USUSUSUSCA` (since US is present 4 times in my database and CA is present one time) (The $countryName variable consists of the name of the countries, same format as above.)

The function then returns this:

```
<option value="US">United States of America</option>
```

My question is though, how can I get the available countries from my database, and then print them out, so each country is only present **once**?

Comment: Either by DISTINCT or GROUP BY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `DISTINCT` to your query:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT country_code,country_name FROM users WHERE country_code!='NA' AND country_name!='NA'");
```

You should also add `print` in your loop:

```
foreach ($rows as $row){
    $countryCode =  $row["country_code"];
    $countryName =  $row["country_name"];   
    print "<option value='$countryCode'>$countryName</option>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Can you tell me how to only show the result, IF there is more than 5 results in the database?

Comment: Add a `HAVING` clause

Comment: How would the query then look like? .. AND country_name!='NA' AND HAVING .. ?